# Run a Power point macro code for other PPTs

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have a macro code named "KillSpecificSlide" for power point. This codes is run behind ppt.If I want to copy the same code to some another ppt or if I want to run the code from One PPT to some other different PPTs then How to do this?

My code is given below:

```
Sub KillSpecificSlide()
 Dim oSld As Slide
 Dim oShp As Shape
 Dim L As Long
 For L = ActivePresentation.Slides.Count To 1 Step -1
 Set oSld = ActivePresentation.Slides(L)
 For Each oShp In oSld.Shapes
 If oShp.HasTextFrame Then
 Select Case UCase(oShp.TextFrame.TextRange)
 Case Is = "Q4", "CJ"
 oSld.Delete
 Case Else
 'not found
 End Select
 End If
 Next oShp
 Next L
 End Sub
```

This is saved in Module 1 of a PPT named BOX.pptm..I want to run the same code for other ppt files by browsing it.

```
Sub PPTTest()
  Dim PPT As Object

  Set PPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")

  PPT.Presentations.Open "D:\Us\70\Desktop\Shaon\BOD.pptx", , , False

  ' Note that the file name and the module
  ' name are required to path the macro correctly.
  PPT.Run "BOD.pptx!Module1.KillSpecificSlide"

 End Sub
```

Comment: Well, show the code... Also, is the code written to address the ppt by name? If so, then you need to control that...

Comment: @Solar Mike I have edited my question above showing my code.

Comment: Looks like you should copy that code to module 1 of the other ppt...

Comment: @solarMike Exactly and want to run it also for that PPT or may be for multiple PPTs.

Comment: @SolarMike Or else I want to run this same code for Multiple ppts available in a same folder.

Comment: It looks as if Ppt does not have the equivalent of a "personal Macro workbook" like Excel, so you may need to copy that code to each ppt you want it to work on or perhaps consider an "automator" script if you are on a mac...

Comment: @solarMike If I want to do it then how to proceed??Also if I want to write a code in excel run the code for different PPTs then how to do it?

Comment: @SolarMike Can you please modify my code to do the requirement?

Answer (score 1):

```
Option Explicit

Sub listOpenPresentations()
    Dim myPpt As Presentation

    Debug.Print "Open ppt's : "; Application.Presentations.Count & vbCrLf
    For Each myPpt In Application.Presentations
        Debug.Print myPpt.Name

        Call Add_and_Delete_Slide(myPpt)

    Next myPpt
End Sub

Sub Add_and_Delete_Slide(locPPT As Presentation)
    Dim pptSlide As Slide
    Dim pptLayout As CustomLayout
    Dim actWindow As Variant

    For Each actWindow In Windows
        If actWindow.Caption = locPPT.Name Then actWindow.Activate
    Next actWindow

    Set pptLayout = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).CustomLayout
    Set pptSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides.AddSlide(2, pptLayout)
    MsgBox "Slide 2 added in """ & ActivePresentation.Name & """"

    ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Delete
    MsgBox "Slide 2 deleted in """ & ActivePresentation.Name & """"
End Sub
```

Comment: Can You please tell me open a ppt using vba dialogue box and Save that ppt  in a variable?

Comment: @Shaon why don't you try and edit that vba code to add what you need - it will be good experience...

Comment: @SolarMike I have done that...But somehow its hardcoded..I want to make it global...I am going to add that code above..Its hardcoded...